# How to wait until function returns a value (React js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hay everyone, I made a short react js function that called `"ChartPage"` that gets a value from `getCoin` function and then passes the value to `Chart` component I made. But my code for some reason isn't waiting for `getCoin` to return the value and continues in the code and calls to `Chart` with an 'undefined' as the value.
Can someone help me make `"ChartPage"` waits until `getCoin` functions returns the value that I need to pass?
**this is my code:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../App.css";
import Chart from "../Chart";
import { Button } from "../Button.js";
import "./ChartPage.css";
import axios from "axios";

function getCoin(data) {
  var path = `/show-stocks/${data}`;
  axios.get(path).then((response) => {
    return response.data;
  });
}

export default function ChartPage({ data }) {
  var values = getCoin(data); // "values" is the variable I want to pass to "Chart"
  return (
    <>
      <div className="chart-page-container">
        <h1>{data} Price Market Value</h1>
        <div className="chart-container">
          <Chart data={values} /> {/* here I am passing "values" to "Chart" component*/}
        </div>
        <div className="chart-page-btns">
          <Button
            link="/show-stocks/bitcoin"
            className="btns"
            buttonStyle="btn--outline2"
            buttonSize="btn--large2"
          >
            Bitcoin
          </Button>
          <Button
            link="/show-stocks/ethereum"
            className="btns"
            buttonStyle="btn--outline2"
            buttonSize="btn--large2"
          >
            Ethereum
          </Button>
          <Button
            link="/show-stocks/cardano"
            className="btns"
            buttonStyle="btn--outline2"
            buttonSize="btn--large2"
          >
            Cardano
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Specific to React... Instead of trying to synchronously get your value, you should store your value in state.  The asynchronous operation would simply update that state.

Comment: Check this one: https://jsfiddle.net/j6z735wf/ , i can't post an answer here but copy the snippet from the url :)

Comment: can you show me code example of what you are referring to